# Changing admin menu style

Tags: opencart

I want to change my admin menu, Horizontal to vertical . I have attached the Screenshot for the same.

please suggest me how to do that.

thanks!
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCHgO.png)

in my opencart->admin->view->common->header.tpl

menu is like this

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"><img src="view/image/logo.png" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" onclick="location = '<?php echo $home; ?>'" /></div>
    <?php if ($logged) { ?>
    <div class="div3"><img src="view/image/lock.png" alt="" style="position: relative; top: 3px;" />&nbsp;<?php echo $logged; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php if ($logged) { ?>
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="left" style="display: none;">
      <li id="dashboard"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>" class="top"><?php echo $text_dashboard; ?></a></li>
      <li id="catalog"><a class="top"><?php echo $text_catalog; ?></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $text_category; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $product; ?>"><?php echo $text_product; ?></a></li>
          <li><a class="parent"><?php echo $text_attribute; ?></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="<?php echo $attribute; ?>"><?php echo $text_attribute; ?></a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo $attribute_group; ?>"><?php echo $text_attribute_group; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $option; ?>"><?php echo $text_option; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>"><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $download; ?>"><?php echo $text_download; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $review; ?>"><?php echo $text_review; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $information; ?>"><?php echo $text_information; ?></a></li>
```

I want this menu to be displayed vertically instead of horizontal.

in stylesheet, menu is defined like this

```
#menu {
    background: url('../image/menu.png') repeat-x;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 34px;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    min-width: 900px;
}
#menu > ul.left {
    float: left;
}
#menu > ul.right {
    float: right;
}
#menu > ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu > ul ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url('../image/transparent.png');
}
#menu > ul a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
#menu > ul > li + li {
    background: url('../image/split.png') center left no-repeat;
}
#menu > ul .top, #menu > ul li li.sfhover {
    padding: 10px 15px 9px 17px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu > ul ul li {
    padding: 2px;
}
#menu > ul .selected .top {
    background: url('../image/selected.png') repeat-x;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu > ul .selected:hover a.top, #menu > ul .sfhover a.top {
}
#menu > ul .parent {
    background: url('../image/arrow-right.png') 95% center no-repeat;
}
#menu > ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu > ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
#menu > ul li li {
    clear: both;
}
#menu > ul li ul a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 15px;
    width: 145px;
}
#menu > ul li ul ul {
    margin: -27px 0 0 157px;
}
#menu > ul li li:hover, #menu > ul li li.sfhover {
    background: #333;
    color: #000000;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

here i am not getting how to change this. So please suggest me where exactly i should change

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have tried changing it in the stylesheet, menu widt. but couldnt get

Comment: We can't just work from a screenshot. At least put something up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can work with. Give us some code to work with. And that doesn't mean the entire page's HTML and CSS, only relevant code. You have to put some effort into the question for anyone to help with an answer.

Comment: I have edited my post. Please have a look

Comment: OK, you're using lists to make the menu. Look at the tutorials [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/) for horizontal list menus. One of those will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easiest if you change the images to your images or background-colors of your choice and then put a break after every

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $attribute; ?>"><?php echo $text_attribute; ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $attribute_group; ?>"><?php echo $text_attribute_group; ?></a></li>
</ul><br/>
```

To Change heading names remove the php text and add your own.

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $category; ?>">Add/Edit Category</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $product; ?>">Add/Edit Products</a></li>
```

If you want an accordion function then you just need to download this [jquery script](http://www.p51labs.com/accordion/) or another like it, in which case you don't even have to worry about that mess of css styling and you can write a far simpler version from scratch.

***UPDATE**
To create the accordion navigation follow the tutorial [**here**](http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion.html). I recommend demo 1 for your purposes.

I also recommend posting a new question if you need help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying it out.But after 1st <li> if i give break it is not coming jyst below the Dashboard or 1st menu. How to adjust the space there. Please guide

Comment: Do you want to try it after the '</ul>'s instead of the '</li>'s?

Comment: No. I want to use only after <li> but arrangement is not proper. Ex: I want my second menu Catalog to display just below the 1st menu Dashboard after giving a break tag. Bu its not happening.

Comment: Like this? [link](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_simple_accordion_menu.htm#)

Comment: Hey exactly like this i want to have. Can ou please guide me. Please

Comment: I have updated my answer for you. The tutorial I posted should be perfect for you.